# Ionic 3 - Ms Adal :: How to cache data and resend it

Tags: ionic3, angular5, adal

Below is my working Code for MS ADAL with Ionic 3.

```
const SsoConfig = {
      "authority": "https://login.windows.net/common",
      "resourceUrl": "https://graph.windows.net",
      "clientId": [clientId]
      "redirectUrl": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"
    };

let authContext: AuthenticationContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext(SsoConfig.authority);
authContext.acquireTokenAsync(SsoConfig.resourceUrl, SsoConfig.clientId, SsoConfig.redirectUrl, "", "")
      .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
        console.log(authResponse);
      })
      .catch((e: any) => {
        console.log('Authentication failed')
      });
```

Now, with the above code I have to login every time. Its not storing the data. So, I tried with the below code, but its not working.

```
authContext.tokenCache.readItems().then(function (catchItems: any) {
      if (catchItems.length > 0) {
        authority = catchItems[0].authority;
        console.log(catchItems);
      }

      authContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync(SsoConfig.resourceUrl, SsoConfig.clientId, "")
        .then((silentAuthResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
          console.log(silentAuthResponse);
        })
        .catch((e: any) => {          
          authContext.acquireTokenAsync(SsoConfig.resourceUrl, SsoConfig.clientId, SsoConfig.redirectUrl, "", "")
            .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {              
              console.log(authResponse);
            })
            .catch((e: any) => {
              this.Message = "Authentication failed";
              console.log(e)
            });
        });;
    });
```

Could someone help me on this??

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?
I want to do the same thing.

Comment: Sorry. NO. I'm not able to find a proper solution for this. The "catchItems" automatically store the data which we get as a response, but its not the proper way. The problem is, when a user change the password in the browser, the cached data could not detect it.

Comment: Also, the is an auth-connect in Ionic enterprise. https://ionicframework.com/blog/ionic-auth-connect-single-sign-on-made-easy. I never tried that. You can try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the ionic storage plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage or the sqlite plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage to store the data.